# Error de Django

Tags: mysql, python, sql, django, django-models

Estoy realizando un proyecto con Django 3.1.4 y Python 3.6.0, pero al querer hacer la conexión con la base de datos (MySQL) la consola me arroja el siguiente error: "django.core.exceptions.improperlyconfigured mysqlclient 1.4.0 or newer is required you have 0.10.1"  . Alguién sabe a qué se deba o que este causando ese error? Como puedo solucionarlo?
Adjunto captura de la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ese mensaje dice que necesitas instalar **mysqlclient**

Solo tienes que instalarlo a través de pip

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: Si pero al hacer ese comando me sale "Command errored out with status 1:" Y una larga lista de errores en color rojo

Comment: @AlejandroJose intenta instalar tu proyecto django en un entorno virtual, de la misma manera que instalas django a través de pip asi mismo puedes instalar el mysqlclient

Comment: ¿Qúe errores te da cuando das el pip install mysqlclient? Generalmente en el log te dice si te falta alguna dependencia más. Si lo compartes es mas facil poder ayudarte. Exito!!!